# backbone/requirejs view strange benavior

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

i m doing reverse engineering and comepletely cant get how my backbone/requirejs view script works. Because requirejs documentation says that names of modules must be the same, but here is the code which works with just "a,b,c,d" modules declaration. can somebody help what should i read to understand?

```
"use strict";
define([
   "underscore",
   "backbone",
   "jquery",
   "util/numeral",
   "text!sa-utils/js/templates/KeyIndicatorResults.html",
   "css!sa-utils/css/KeyIndicator.css"],
function(a,b,c,d,e,f){
  var g = some code working
  return g
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Names of modules are what you see in the dependencies array as strings (`[
   "underscore", ...]`)

`a,b,c,...` here are just arguments names, it is JavaScript and RequireJS doesn't have anything to do with what the developer decided to name them. Here they are meaningless because you are likely looking at uglified code.